# Image upload not showing image (Guillotine Crop)

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, crop, image-uploading

I have a simple image upload which goes into an `iframe` on page *index.php*:

```
<form ...action="up.php">
<input type="file" value="" name="file" id="file"> 
<iframe style="" id="upload_target" name="upload_target"</iframe>
</form>
```

The image is uploaded with *up.php* using PHP:

```
<?php
...
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$path");
...
list($test_width, $test_height) = getimagesize($path); 
?>
```

Now I want to show the image in the `iframe` and allow cropping with `guillotine` (still *up.php*):

```
<?php
if($test_width>0) {
?>

<div id="theparent" style="width: 100%;border:0px solid #000;">
  <img id='tempImage2' src='<?php echo $path;?>'>
</div>
```

Until here it works, but `guillotine` now does something which causes the image not to show. The next part is from the [Guillotine Crop](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine):

```
<div id='controls'>
  <button id='zoom_out'     type='button' title='Zoom out'> - </button>
  <button id='fit'          type='button' title='Fit image'> [ ]  </button>
  <button id='zoom_in'      type='button' title='Zoom in'> + </button>
</div>

<div style="display:none">
  <ul id='data'>
    <div class='column'>
      <span id='x'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='column'>
      <li>width:  <span id='w'></span>
      <li>height: <span id='h'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='column'>
      <li>scale: <span id='scale'></span>
      <li>angle: <span id='angle'></span>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>

<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'></script>
<script src='../../jCrop/js/jquery.guillotine.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function() {
  var picture = $('#tempImage2');
  picture.on('load', function(){
    // Initialize plugin (with custom event)
    picture.guillotine({eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange'});

    // Display inital data
    var data = picture.guillotine('getData');
    for(var key in data) { $('#'+key).html(data[key]); }

    // Bind button actions
    $('#rotate_left').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('rotateLeft'); });
    $('#rotate_right').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('rotateRight'); });
    $('#fit').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('fit'); });
    $('#zoom_in').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('zoomIn'); });
    $('#zoom_out').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('zoomOut'); });

    // Update data on change
    picture.on('guillotinechange', function(ev, data, action) {
      data.scale = parseFloat(data.scale.toFixed(4));
      for(var k in data) { $('#'+k).html(data[k]); }
    });
  });
});

var otherPicture = $('#tempImage2');
otherPicture.guillotine({eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange'});
otherPicture.on('guillotinechange', function(ev, data, action){
});

</script>

<?php
}
?>
```

When I reload the `iframe`, the image is shown. This make me believe the image is not loaded when it wants to show it? But I thought PHP loaded first, which loads the JavaScript when the file exists (`$test_width>0`).

Comment: Seems it is only not working on Google Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something odd in your code, you are instantiating the plugin twice for the same image. `picture` and `otherPicture` are actually the same DOM element. That's surely one source of issues.

Other than that the code for the first instance seems about right, correctly wrapped in a callback for the picture's `onload` event. Be aware that if the image finishes loading before you bind to the `onload` event (e.g. cached image) the callback won't be executed.

Also, to avoid complications with iframes you might want to use something like [Bifrost](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/bifrost). It extends jQuery's `ajax` to asynchronously upload files when HTML5 features aren't supported and without Flash.

In the background it **creates** and handles an **iframe** for you, so essentially it would be the same but this way you can keep the Guillotine in your main frame instead of inside the iframe.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, the odd thing was indeed the issue.